# .htaccess rewrite rule confusion/conflicts

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the below rewrite rules setup on a site. I' trying to set it up so I have the below different URLs.

**Current .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

**Required URLs**

```
www.site.com
www.site.com/page/
www.site.com/product-1234/
www.site.com/privacy-policy/
```

The problem is that the second rewrite rule is affecting the `privacy-polcy` url but it shouldn't as the second rewrite rule is specific only to the product pages that have the product ID in it.

I'm also trying to ignore directories that exist as the structure of my site so under root I have the below directories which I don't want the rewrite rules to affect as the user shouldn't know anything about these directories.

```
/system/
/tasks/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# catch more specific urls:
RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]*)/$ ?action=product&id=$1 [L]

# ignore requests that want files or directories that do exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# then continue with the less specific:
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L]
```